# Entity Framework Invalid Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've looked at lots of other questions on SO but can't get the answer.  I have a column in a table called: Sex - Male

I would like to get my hands on whoever named it as it's giving me problems with EF.  If I use this:

```
[Column("Sex - Male")]
public bool Sex { get;set; }
```

This gives me the error of being incompatible with the model as the field "Sex" could not be found.  So I changed to this:

```
[Column("[Sex - Male]")]
public bool Sex { get;set; }
```

I then get the message Invalid Column Name [Sex - Male].  Does EF rename columns with spaces in some way as the field does exist and is not any kind of FK?

EDIT

I have found that doing this in the modelBuilder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(x => x.Sex).HasColumnName("Sex - Male");
```

Causes the same error to appear saying it's incompatible as there is no column called Sex with the same name!  I've noticed it occurs on anything I use the Column data annotation for not just this field!

EDIT 2

I created a new application and used a Model Designer to see how it interpreted the column and showed it in the designer as "Sex___Male", however, changing the class to this even with []'s around it still gives me could not find column Sex___Male??

EDIT 3

It appears the error isn't quite what I thought, I found the mapping config works fine when I just use db.Students; and the column is there as expected.
It turns out the area going wrong is this line:

```
var students = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<Student>(sql);
```

So it's clearly the ExecuteStoreQuery that I'm guessing won't use the same mapping configuration therefore sees the column as missing.  Not sure why putting the Column annotation on the property in the class doesn't work though??

Comment: Check your model diagram for the correct name, you can rename it to anything you wish.

Comment: What's the SQL type?  `Bit` is normally associated with boolean values.

Comment: Are you mapping to existing database, or doing code first?

Comment: Not using diagrams, using classes.
The field is indeed a bit.
I am using Existing Database.

Comment: It's actually happening on other models where I use the [Column] attribute?

Comment: Is there possibly a way to test EF to see how it's getting the Column?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Comment: 4.4 according to web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Entity Framework itself had no issue mapping this column regarding it's normal use however the issue I had is where I was using the ExecuteStoreQuery method to map the model.

It turns out using this means anything you map it to has to have the same names regardless of any data annotations you add on for column (they appear to just get ignored).  What I did instead was make a small class with just the fields I needed and changed the sql of the query to Select StudentID As ID, [Sex - Male] As Sex, ...other fields FROM ...etc i.e.

```
public class StudentReadOnly 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get;set; }
    ... other properties
}
```

And then changed line to:

```
var students = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<StudentReadOnly>(sql);
```

And had no problems.  I also found that any properties you put in the class MUST exist in the sql query unlike a usual ef query.

Answer (score 2):

I have recreated your situation in a test configuration. I was able to succesfully insert and query data using the following configuration

- SQL Server 2012
- Visual Studio 2013
- Entity Framework 6.0.1

If you are using an older version of Entity Framework I would consider updating; that's most likely the cause, however I'm not able to reproduce your environment so this answer is only a guess. I used this code:

Created a table:

```
create table MyTable2 (
[pk] int not null identity primary key, 
[Sex - Male] bit not null);
```

Class:

```
public class MyTable2
{
    public int pk { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping configuration:

```
this.HasKey(t => t.pk);
this.Property(t => t.Sex).HasColumnName("Sex - Male");
```

Comment: Is updating from 4.4 likely to cause any compatibility issues?

Comment: @user1166905 I always had positive experiences with updating entity framework. You should create a backup just to make sure. There are no breaking changes, except for pre-generated views http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896240(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: Ok, it's a big project so a little reluctant, I'll give it a go GULP

Comment: As suspected, build errors everywhere now I've updated. First one is Error 11 The type or namespace name 'EntityState' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Comment: Have found it's now in System.Data.Entity for anyone else who upgrades

Comment: @user1166905 http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6

Comment: Updated but still get: The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Models.Student'. A member of the type, 'Sex', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.  

I've got this in modelBuilder: modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().Property(n => n.Sex).HasColumnName("Sex - Male");

If I wrap the text with []'s for the spaces it gives a different error to say the column doesn't exist.

Comment: @user1166905 what version of SQL Server are you using? I tried .NET 4.0  as well, and multiple ways to map, but they all seem to work.

Comment: 2008 R2, I'm unable to update this though as several clients use this application in 2008 as well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40575/discussion-between-bas-brekelmans-and-user1166905)